# JSON String using POST client

Tags: java, json, post

Hello all i am trying to capture the json "post" data from the client and send it to other client i.e i am trying to get the data of the client who hit my url and i handle this data and send it to the actual url.For this i have created an internal post client where i handle the data and send to my actual url.

```
URL url = new URL(urlPath);
    conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    String a = book.getId();
    String b = book.getName();
    String c = book.getAuthor();
    String d = book.getPrice();

    System.out.println(a + b + c + d);

    byte[] out = "{\"id\":\"root\",\"name\":\"password\",\"price\":\"root\",\"author\":\"password\"}"
            .getBytes();
    int length = out.length;

    conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(length);
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
            "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    conn.connect();
    OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
    os.write(out);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            conn.getInputStream()));
    while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
        response = output;
    }
    // return parseJSON(response);
    return response;
```

I want to place my values of the strings a,b,c,d with the root,password,root,password respectively.

But when i try to place it i get the error insert missing quote.

Please help me regarding this

Thank you

Comment: did you try putting the `"` properly? try this out...

"{\"id\":\"" + a + "\",\"name\":\"" +b+"\",\"price\":\"" + c+" \",\"author\":\"" + d+ "\"}"

Comment: yes when i tried this  it takes as string but i need bytes in order to write this output

Comment: you can get the byte array from the string using this.

new String("{\"id\":\"" + a + "\",\"name\":\"" +b+"\",\"price\":\"" + c+" \",\"author\":\"" + d+ "\"}").getBytes()

Comment: that worked out.Thank you so much.so does it create a new string and return it.

Comment: Yes. It does. you can also use StringBuilder if you want to do so. Can i add this as an answer and you can accept it ?.

Comment: yes you can i will do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving Comment to Answer as it worked for OP.

you can convert string to byte array as below:

```
byte[] request =  new String("{\"id\":\"" + a + "\",\"name\":\"" +b+"\",\"price\":\"" + c+" \",\"author\":\"" + d+ "\"}").getBytes()
```